# $U_{0}=\{[a^{0},a^{1},…,a^{n}]\in \mathbb{R}P^{n}\,:\,a^{0}\neq 0\}$. Is it open in $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$?

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

Is $U_{0}$ an open neighborhood of a $[a^{0},a^{1},…,a^{n}] \in \mathbb{R}P^{n}$ ? How can I prove that? It tried to see if $\pi^{-1}(U_{0})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\smallsetminus\{0\}$. I see that $$\pi^{-1}(U_{0}) = (\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\setminus\left(\{a^{1}\neq0\}\cup\{a^{2}\neq0\}\cup\dots\cup\{a^{n}\neq0\}\right)$$Where $\{a^{j} \neq 0\}$ is just the axis of the j-st coordinate. Is this set open in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\smallsetminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Or did you mean this? $$U_0=\{[a^0,a^1,\cdots,a^n]\in\Bbb RP^n\text{ such that }a^0\ne 0\}$$ Be careful that "$\backslash$" is not the same as "$\mid$": the first one is difference of sets, the second one is sometimes used (like "$:$") as a synonimous of "such that".

Comment: such that $a^{0} \neq 0$! (We use all of them to say "such that"). And now that it's clear? You can see Loring Tu pg 80, [link](http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf) to understand better.

Comment: You also use (third line: $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$) "\setminus" for the difference of sets, which is rather confusing: I challenge you to argue that "\setminus" and "\backslash" are different symbols.

Comment: I said. We normally use "\backslash" to symbol "such that" and the other symbols that you mentioned as well. I prefer "\backslash". So my case is the second in your comments, I just used the same notation on two totally different things (Which we do normally here, I got a math degree using this notation to symbolize "such that" in sets). Sorry.

Comment: That's very strange.  As G. Sassatelli said, most commonly "|" is used to denote "such that" in sets, less common is ":".    I have never seen "\" used that way.

Comment: Why is strange? "|" is very similar to "\" and you can tell when it's referred to "such that" or the difference of sets. Anyway, mathematics are invariant under notation.

Answer (score 2):

$\pi^{-1}(U_0)=\{(x_0,\cdots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid x_0\ne 0\}$

Which is open in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ by definition of product topology. Hence, $\pi^{-1}(U_0)$ is open in $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$. Hence, by definition of quotient topology, $U_0$ is open.