# Open subset of $\mathbb {CP}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, projective-space

As picture below, how to show the $U_i$ is open subset of $\mathbb {CP}^n$ ?

> [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$U_{0}=\{[a^{0},a^{1},…,a^{n}]\in \mathbb{R}P^{n}\,:\,a^{0}\neq 0\}$. Is it open in $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633227/u-0-a0-a1-an-in-mathbbrpn-a0-neq-0-is-it-open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the quotient map $f: \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^n$ by $f(z)=[z]$.

Clearly, $V_i = f^{-1}(U_i)$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with $i$-th coordinate is not equal to $0$. Then what is the complement of $V_i$? It is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ which is closed.

For example, for $n=1$, $(V_0)^c$ is the $x$-axis and $(V_1)^c$ is the $y$-axis whereas for $n=2$, $(V_0)^c$ is the $yz$-plane.

Comment: I assumed the topology on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is the quotient topology not Zariski topology.

Comment: Let me add for clarity that $f$ is continuous, by the very definition of the quotient topology.

Comment: It is the quotient map?

Comment: @Levent: Yes, it is, and your argument is fine.

Comment: @Levent  It is should be quotient topology.

Answer (score 0):

The space is irreducible, and so having $U_i$ as a dense subset, means that $U_i$ is open.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the OP was looking for an elementary argument.

Comment: @AlexM. Does elementary mean easy?(Serious question, I am not sure)

Comment: Your answer assumes that the OP knows what "irreducible" means (and this is usually taught in courses on algebraic geometry, not sure if the OP has had any), that the knows how to prove it, and that he also knows how to prove that $U_i$ is dense (in fact, is it? we are not working with the Zariski topology here). Plus, are you sure that the results that you mention don't already use the fact that the sets $U_i$ are open? By "elementary" I mean conceptually simple, i.e. deducible from first principles.

Comment: @AlexM.  Although I know what mean the irreducible is, but it is not obvious that $CP^n$ is irreducible.

Comment: You're right. I thought this was in the context of algebraic geometry, my apologies. @AlexM. (and took $\Bbb{CP}^n$ to mean $\Bbb P^n$ over an algebraiclly closed field.(Zariski topology))